# What's the 'right' way to add javascript to wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a function in functions.php that is enqueuing my script.js. 
Everything works fine.
But, I only want that script to run on single.php. 
Now it is running on every single page.
Is there a way to 'control' on what page the script should run on?

My function looks like this:

```
function mytheme_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', array(), '1.0.0');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_script_enqueue' );
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213742/how-to-load-js-and-css-only-on-specific-pages-using-is-page

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement in the function. See below:

```
function mytheme_script_enqueue() {
        wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0');
        if(is_single()){ //or any way to target the page you want
            wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', array(), '1.0.0');
        }
    }    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_script_enqueue' );
```